# Creating custom activity design without reference to Design DLL in Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, system.componentmodel

I am using **Windows Workflow Foundation** with **custom Activities**, and I would like to create **custom Design** for these activities in my workflow.

I am able to make the design project, and the designer xaml. Also I am able to see the custom design for them in the workflow, **if I directly refer the Design project in my Workflow project**.

This is something that I would not like to do, because the Designer DLL should not be deployed to production environment. I would only like to have the custom design in Visual Studio workflow editor.

I was able to get things working by adding following:

```
[Designer("namespace,dll")]
public class CustomActivity : NativeActivity<string>
```

and after this copying the dll to visual studio path. This is again something that I would not like to do, because every developer should do this and making the build so that the dll is copied some fixed visual studio path is not very good.

I used these two examples, but it seems that both of these directly refer the DLL:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/jkurtz/archive/2010/01/26/137639.aspx
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-9e867448

I would assume this kind of feature would somehow be supported by the Visual Studio/Workflow Foundation.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: There is an overload for DesignerAttribute that takes two strings, if I recall.  One is the namespace, the other the type name, I believe.  If you use that, you can avoid references.  But you do have to 1) load the assembly manually into the designer AppDomain, or 2) follow the rules of how designer assemblies are located.  For visual studio, I documented these in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886905/1228).  Not sure if that is enough to answer your question.  What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
If you check I am actually using the two strings overload. I checked your answer on other question and it seems to verify my previous findings that DLL can be copied under visual studio folder and things can work that way, but like I mentioned I would not prefer that solution.
I also quickly tried the GAC solution (to register dll to GAC when to solution is built), but I was not able to get it working. I should probably try it again.

Comment: Sorry, actually I am using the one string overload, my bad :) I will check that also.

Comment: Two string overload didn't help, also the GAC solution doesn't seem to work, I was able to register and see the dll in GAC, but the visual studio is not loading things there.

still good ideas, do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio (at least the version out at the time of that answer) has very specific requirements as to how it locates designer assemblies.  Any rehosted designer that would support the string-not-type designer attribute overload would also, similarly, have to locate the designer dll by convention.  So, AFAICT, you have to follow VS' convention.  Alternatively, use a preprocessor directive to switch between the way you use the DesignerAttribute, deliver DEBUG to devs, and RELEASE to servers.

Answer (score 0):

The `Designer` attribute (using "magic" string) is not something very reliable. If you change your class name or namespace, you'll not have a compilation error.
There is another (better imho) way to do it using `IRegisterMetadata` implementation:

1. Your **Design** assembly must reference your activity assembly, but this usually can't be avoided.
2. Add a partial class (.cs) to your XAML designer
3. This class must inherit from `System.Activities.Presentation.Metadata.IRegisterMetadata`. this interface only define one method to implement.

Here is a implementation sample:

```
public void Register()
{
    AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
    builder.AddCustomAttributes(
        typeof(MyActivity),
        new DesignerAttribute(typeof(MyActivityDesigner)));
    MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
}
```

Next, you'll want to have the custom designer used in Visual Studio. Visual Studio have strict rules to automatically load designer assemblies. You need:

1. Your designer project must have the same name than your activity project, with ".Design" added at the end. Example:

   - Activiy project: MyApp.Activities.dll
   - Designer project: MyApp.Activities.Design.dll
2. The .Design dll must be in the same directory than the activity dll. You can automate this with a post build event in the designer project.

**Important Edit:**

I see now that your links already present this method but you say that it directly reference the DLL. Yes, the DESIGN dll reference the ACTIVITY dll.
But you asked the opposite: the activity dll shouldn't reference the design dll.
Using the IRegisterMetadata method, your DESIGN dll can reference the ACTIVITY dll, it's not a problem: you can remove the design dll from the released package, the activity dll will work fine.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have tried the exact configuration that you provided but I am unable to get it working. Referring the Activity DLL from the Design DLL is totally ok, and this is how I have been using it.
That configuration is very similar how it is done in examples, but in both examples there is this third standalone editor project that refers both DLL's, and it makes things working in these examples. Only place where visual studio is looking for the Design DLL's is from within it's own IDE folder (I have monitored the dll lookup with dll monitoring tools).

Comment: So copying the DLL to Visual Studio folder works, and the design is visible. To my opinion this proves that the metadata registering itself is OK and the naming of DLL is working.

Comment: I also had hard time to get it working, but I can make it work without copying the DLL to VS folder. And I've only 2 projects, (activities/designers) so the binding is in the designer dll, not in a 3rd project. Check your reference to the activity dll, maybe you don't reference it in the output folder (?). The .Design dll must be in the same folder. Sorry I've no more tips to help you.

Comment: Ok, so there is hope :) I will retry this with simplified project from the scratch.